# Google Chrome kiosk mode compatibility on a touch screen monitor

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, kiosk-mode

I'm trying to develop a kiosk web application that uses Google Chrome on kiosk mode setup which loads automatically after start-up.
http://www.sitepoint.com/google-chrome-kiosk-mode/

The kiosk web application also uses a virtual keyboard plugin for Google Chrome for the text inputs.
http://xontab.com/Apps/VirtualKeyboard

I'm planning to setup a computer unit with a touch screen monitor for the kiosk.

Note: It's my first time to develop a web application that uses the kiosk mode setup for Google Chrome and I don't have a touch screen monitor for testing. I wanted to ask this question for developers that has experience with this.

My question is:

1. Does Google Chrome on kiosk mode setup automatically detects my touch screen monitor?
2. Does Google Chrome automatically enables touch features when my web application is on kiosk mode such as swipe for scrolling up and down.

Answer (score 2):

A touch screen is an input device just like a computer mouse - Google Chrome receives touch events the same way it receives mouse events (although the events are different).

The annoying thing when starting working with touch screens is that the standard click event that we are used to, is triggered after a delay comparing to mouse event. You should listen for tap event or use a library such as https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Making long story short developing a kiosk application integrated with a touch screen is similar to developing mobile websites. You should probably use a JavaScript library to support all kind of touch events such as tap, swipe etc. See http://hammerjs.github.io/

You may also find this website useful http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is six years later but for anyone reading this. You can run Google Chrome in Kiosk Mode with custom options. This can be done by creating a new account and right clicking (in windows 10) on the icon for this account.

Under properties add the following tags to optimize the application for touchscreen use:

```
–-touch-events –enable-viewport
```